# Where is the best place to download old versions of MySQL server

Tags: mysql, legacy

I'm restoring an old server, and I need a copy of MySQL 4.1 for windows.  MySql.com only seems to have versions going back to 5.0.  I've seen old versions elsewhere, but they all seem to be from fairly sketchy websites.  Is there a good unofficial place to get old versions of MySql or other software?

Comment: someone voted to close this question.  Although I used the word "best" in the subject I don't think this is an entirely useless political question.  If you vote to close, can you please do me the courtesy of telling me why.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I did flag for migration to SU; the question has nothing to do with programming or the workings of computers.  MySQL is merely a MacGuffin.

Comment: I think it's a red herring.

Comment: The moment you use the word "best" the question is too subjective. What is it you don't like about "sketchy websites"?

Comment: @DrFredEdison, Try http://oldversion.com, or maybe http://www.joho.se/2012/06/20/locating-older-version-of-mysql-4-mysql-5-etc/

Comment: Try to check it here - [https://www.my-old-version.com/mysql/](https://www.my-old-version.com/mysql/) Previous versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.   So it turns out, that a lot of mirrors MySQL uses for current versions still have old versions sitting on their servers.  So, what I did was pretend like I was going to download a newer version, then I got a URL of mirror from the download page from there and explored the mirror manually, finding binaries for 4.1

Comment: Are these mirrors trustworthy? For example, can we trust the binaries on http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/ ?

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of [searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:%22index+of+*%22+mysql-4.0.1)?

Comment: Careful, you'll be getting yourself some viruses.....

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from here:

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/databases/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some virus inside those binaries?

Answer (score 2):

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/databases/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/mysql-4.1.22-win32.zip ^^

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some virus inside those binaries?

Comment: No. No one can be. They are after us! They are after you. They will get you!

Comment: Hopefully MySQL could designate a couple of "official" mirrors, trusted by extension. Currently what I did was to download from multiple mirrors and make sure all of them are byte for byte equal before proceeding with unzipping.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at their tech support page, you can officially want an old version of mysql. This all depends if its worth it to you than to download from those sketchy places.

[link text](http://www.mysql.com/support/vintage.html)

quote:
`2 - Sign up for MySQL Vintage Support
For those customers where upgrading MySQL is not an option, MySQL Vintage Support provides ongoing support for older MySQL versions beyond their EOL date. With MySQL Vintage Support you can continue using MySQL versions, beyond their EOL dates, and continue to receive 24x7 Support, and access to pre-existing patches and KB articles. Additionally, with MySQL Vintage Support, you can also contract for custom bug fixes and custom builds for EOLed products.`

Comment: Link down............... "Page Not Found"